# Error Message Always shows 500 in production environment in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, abort

Throughout my Laravel website I have been using the `abort(404)` helper for throwing errors in my application and showing custom error pages I have made.

Everything works fine, until I change `APP_DEBUG` in the .env to `false` when going live.

Now for every page where I had thrown say a 404 error, it shows error 500 no matter what.

Comment: some mis-configuration in web server, mostly infinite recursive redirect. check the web server log to get the details

Comment: @bansi Thanks, how would I go about fixing this now?

Comment: Please do `tail -f storage/logs/laravel.log` and check what error you get.

Comment: @bansi okay I tried that, I'm not seeing anything that would be relevant to this problem